# Change router's web admin

Tags: router

How to change DLINK DIR-600 web administration port ? now it's set to 80, I want to change it to 81 so I can host web server on my computer

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't have "remote management" enabled on your router, you shouldn't have to change the port.  If however, you do have and need remote management enabled, you can change the remote management port by accessing the admin page and selecting the "Tools" tab ([see example](http://support.dlink.ca/emulators/dir600/101NA/tools_admin.html)).  Under the "Admin" category you should see a box to change the "Remote Admin Port" (which defaults to 8080).  Change that and you should be on your way.

Answer (score 0):

If your web server supports reverse proxying (Apache does), you can likely configure it so the DLink interface appears as a subdirectory on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your router model but I know on mine when I access the web admin interface, I am able to specify which port the web admin interface uses and whether or not if it uses SSL. I set mine to use SSL and port 8080.